# How to use Regular Expression for username validation of woocommerce registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to allow only fixed length digits as username for my woocommerce store. Is that possible to do?

For that I have edited my `validate_username` function in `user.php`. I have used below code but it's not working.

```
$valid = ( preg_match( "/\d{10,10}/", $username ) && ! empty( $sanitized ) );
```

I am very new for woocommerce as well for wordpress. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Just use `/\d{10}/`

Comment: I have tried that but it's allowing more than 10 digits.

Comment: Yep. You have to add `^` and `$` to make an exact match like @Shady Atef offers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
^\d{10}$
```

Explanation

`^` asserts position at start of the string

`\d{10}` matches 10 digits

`$` asserts position at end of the string

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with wordpress or woocommerce, but in normal php you can just do something like this `if (strlen($username) < 11)` or `if (strlen($username) <= 10)`

Comment: You are making it more complex then it needs to be with `preg_match`